# Error in updating google play store

Tags: google-play-store

My problem is similar to that posted by Daniel.

Trying to update after i have uninstalled it to factory version. Tried updating, it downloads and gives an error at the time of update. It gives an error code as **924** asking me to troubleshoot. Please help.

Comment: It's hard to understand what post you are referring to if you don't link it. But most playstore errors are explained in our [google-playstore tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info). Admittedly, your 924 seems to be missing there :(

Answer (score 0):

According to [AndroidPIT](https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-solve-google-play-store-errors#nine-two-four), this error *usually occurs when trying to download larger applications. The app downloads, but the error message is displayed, saying the installation was unsuccessful do to an error.*

As solution, the mentioned post suggests to *head to Settings › All › Google Play Store › Uninstall updates. Once you've done this, try downloading the problem app again.*

There's also a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8fIuVk2SpQ) on this issue.

[Another article](https://www.technologyhint.com/fix-google-play-store-error-924/) holds two more approaches:

- simply restarting the device can already solve the issue
- if not, do the same as described above
- if still not, at the place described above clear cache and, if that doesn't help, delete data of the playstore app

More advice might be found by a [simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=google-play-store+error-924) :)